# Unable to copy files from package to WORKDIR

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I tried to copy all files from some package into my WORKDIR in my Dockerfile

My Dockerfile look like this:

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /yahoo_finance_app
COPY requirements.txt /yahoo_finance_app/requirements.txt
COPY /manage_db/* /yahoo_finance_app/manage_db/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY .. .
```

And I execute it with docker-compose which looks like this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  py-api-yahoo-finance:
    build: ./api-yahoo-finance/yahoo
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    container_name: api_yahoo_finance
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
```

The file tree looks like this:

```
├── api_yahoo_finance
   ├── yahoo
      ├── Dockerfile

├── manage_db
```

I try to copy all the files from manage_db into my WORKDIR in my Dockerfile, but I got the following error:

### => ERROR [5/7] COPY /manage_db/* /yahoo_finance_app/manage_db/                                                                                                                    0.0s

> [5/7] COPY /manage_db/* /yahoo_finance_app/manage_db/:

---

lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount563896323/manage_db: no such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'py-api-yahoo-finance' failed to build : Build failed

And I take the relative path, so the folder is existing.

Thanks to all the helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dockerfiles are built in a variety of environments.

As a security and practical requirement Dockerfile commands can only access files that are in the context directory, either directly or in one of its children.

To keep Dockerfiles many levels deep, you can do this:

```yaml
 py-api-yahoo-finance:
    build:
      context: .
      file: ./api-yahoo-finance/yahoo/Dockerfile
```

and then all paths in the Dockerfile will be relative to the project root where the compose.yml is.

Comment: I don't understand how this solution can help me copy the files.

Comment: Your Dockerfile cannot access /manage_db because its not part of the build context, which is ./api-yahoo-finance/yahoo. If you make the build context . then the Dockerfile can access all files under ./ including ./manage_db and ./api-yahoo-finance